# Socket.Recieve Failing When Multithreaded

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, networking

The following piece of code runs fine when parallelized to 4-5 threads, but starts to fail as the number of threads increase somewhere beyond 10 concurrent threads

```
int totalRecieved = 0;
int recieved;
StringBuilder contentSB = new StringBuilder(4000);
while ((recieved = socket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None)) > 0)
{
   contentSB.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, recieved));
   totalRecieved += recieved;
}
```

The `Recieve` method returns with zero bytes read, and if I continue calling the recieve method then I eventually get the exception 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'. So I'm assuming that the host actually sent data and then closed the connection, but for some reason I never received it.

I'm curious as to why this problem arises when there are a lot of threads. I'm thinking it must have something to do with the fact that each thread doesn't get as much execution time and therefore there are some idle time for the threads which causes this error. Just can't figure out why idle time would cause the socket not to receive any data.

**Edit: Just to clarify. Each thread has its own personal socket reading different data.**

Comment: Just to be clear, each Thread has its own socket?

Comment: What's not clear to me is if you have lots of threads reading one socket or one socket per thread?

Comment: Do you know the SocketError code (SocketException.ErrorCode)? Could be a timeout...

Comment: behavour is really strange if to look at code you gave, seems everything is all right in it..
Each client socket being hosted in it's own thread, socket is blocking type, right? Maybe it's really timeout on receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is attempting to use Receive on the same socket on multiple threads.

MSDN documentation for the [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) specifically recommends that a socket's `Receive` method be used only by a single thread one thread during execution.

For an application that requires multiple threads to read data from the same socket, you should either:

- Use `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive`, as recommended by MSDN, or
- Use a single socket read thread to receive packets, then write each packed to a synchronized queue. You may then have multiple threads pull data off of the queue.

Comment: Good point. Guess I'll change to an async approach. Still doesn't understand why a sync approach would fail.

Comment: MSDN specifically states that you should not use `Receive` processing communications with more than one thread. Since execution of threads is non-deterministic, their implementation probably just happened to (or appeared to) work correctly with fewer than 4 threads.

Comment: The MSDN wording is a little confusing, it's not a problem to use `Receive` when you have multiple threads. The issue is attempting to use `Receive` on the same socket on multiple threads. There's no problem using this on two different threads if each thread is handling a different socket.

Comment: The MSDN example also has bugs - for one they don't close the socket in the method that opens the socket and returns a string.

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks, that's what I was trying to say, but I did not really get the point across. The answer has been updated to make it more clear.

Comment: _"For an application that requires multiple threads to read data from the same socket"_ -- the OP has explicitly stated that _"Each thread has its own personal socket"_. It is unfortunate that the OP accepted this answer, as it does not appear to address the OP's scenario, at all.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Yes, but that edit was made months after this answer was written. Maybe you should write you own answer.

Comment: I would write an answer, if there was a good question to answer. The inapplicability of your own answer is a great example of why people shouldn't answer poor questions. Yes, it was only made 100% clear your answer doesn't apply by an edit that occurred after you answered; but there wasn't anything in the question at the outset that supported the answer you gave, regardless.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the downvote and 6 years of hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a system limit on open connections, see for starters [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657874/max-tcp-connections-to-a-machine). And here is some [more info](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html).

Comment: As @Qua did not show how the Socket object is constructed, it is possible that such limit is hit.

Comment: I added a new answer to that question because the accepted answer was wrong. The license imposed limit of 10 is for application protocols provided by MS only. There are other reasons for 10 too...your other link is better as it provides some of these (such as no more than 10 half-open TCP connections, no more than 10 new connections within 1 second).

Comment: @Kevin: I know there are better Q+A about this on SO but I couldn't find them )-: